# Grouping of aggregated data?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I use the following aggregation-query for counting subscribers per day:

```
{
    '$match': {
        'entity': entity.id
    }
},
{
    '$group': { 
        '_id': '$subscribed_at', 
        'sender_id': { 
            '$push': '$sender_id' 
        }
    }
},
{
    '$sort': {
        '_id': 1
    }
}
```

The issue I get using this query is, that it outputs the day and the subscriber as single entries. So my question: How can I modify my query so I get something like:

- Date day 1 => 2 Subscribers in array
- Date day 2 => 3 Subscribers in array
- Date day 3 => 1 Subscriber in array

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `{ $sum: 1 }` in `$group` stage? Could you update your question with some documents and desired result for them?

Comment: update the document of collection in your question

Comment: I think I know what the problem is: As $subscribed_at consists of a raw date (date and time), it doesn't get summed up becuase of the hours. minutes and seconds. how can i reformat the date so it only consists of day, month and year?

Comment: [see link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/hlr6XsB24SM) for formating date